# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, json

I pulled this directly from W3 schools website on their JSON tutorial, but I keep getting an error message **JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "var"** and it's pointing to the line:

"var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myserveraddress/myTutorials.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: As requested here is the link to the W3 page that has the tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp and here is the link that has the demohttp://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_http

Also here is what my myTutorials.txt file looks like

```
var myArray = [
{
"display": "JavaScript Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "HTML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "CSS Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"
}
]
```

Comment: myserveraddress/myTutorials.txt clearly doesn't contain JSON

Comment: Could you recreate the issue using jsfiddle.net and share the link?

Comment: Link to the W3 page the OP is referring to: [JSON Http Request](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp)

Comment: That's another proof not to use w3schools as tutorial...

Comment: @Michael — That page isn't actually all that bad, it's a bit dated, gets a bunch of terminology wrong, and it has some ugly generating-HTML-by-mashing-strings-together, but the problem seems to have been caused by not following it properly.

Comment: @Quentin that's true, but my critic was more against naming a `.json` file `.txt`, which is not best practice in a tutorial for beginners who will learn it wrong because of that. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also here is what my myTutorials.txt file looks like

That's wrong.

You've put the content of the box marked **myArray** in that file.

The contents of the box marked **myTutorials.txt** looks like this:

```
[
{
"display": "JavaScript Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "HTML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "CSS Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"
}
]
```

Comment: That makes sense now. When it said "unexpected identifier var" as the error message, I assumed that it was talking about my html file and not my json file, but it now it is clear. Thanks!